# form radio box ajax value

Tags: ajax

I programmed a form which dynamically calculates the price.
You can select between 2 packages.

```
<input type="radio" id="p1" onclick="doWork();" name="package"/>
<input type="radio" id="p2" onclick="doWork();" name="package"/>
```

In Ajax I send the value to a php file.

```
function doWork(){    
    httpObject = getHTTPObject();
    if (httpObject != null) {
        var url = "price.php?p1=" + document.getElementById('p1').value + "&p2=" + document.getElementById('p2').value;
        httpObject.open("GET", url, true);

        httpObject.send(null); 
        httpObject.onreadystatechange = setOutput;
    }
}
```

Inside the php file I do

```
<?php
    $price = 0;

    if ($_GET['p1'] == 'on') $price += 1;
    if ($_GET['p2'] == 'on') $price += 2;

    echo $price."$";
?>
```

In Safari it shows the right price. But in Firefox I always get the price 3. I doesn't change if I choose 1 or 2 it always is the sum of 1 and 2.

What do I have to change?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite following, where are `p1` and `p2` getting passed? They're not in your current GET request, is there some more code outside the question?

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch the get variables in your PHP page you are using 'p1' and 'p2'. It looks like the url of your Ajax is being set to `price.php?pbasic=" + document.getElementById('p1').value + "&ppro=" + document.getElementById('p2').value` so it appears there's some name mix-ups.

Comment: Ok. I forgot to change this value when I copied it. I have corrected it. In Firefox it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. In Safari it return the value
"on" for p1 and "" for p2 if p1 is selected and
"" for p1 and "on" for p2 if p2 is selected.

In Firefox is return the value "on" for p1 and "on" for p2 if p1 is selected or p2. They always both have the value "on" in Firefox.

Comment: Can I do dynamic price calculation with an existing framework?